Showing that $M^T(N-N^T)$ is a continuous local martingale for all stopping times $T$ and continuous local martingales $M,N$
Given is that a cadlag adapted process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale if and only if $\mathbb{E}X_T=\mathbb{E}X_0$ and $X_T\in L^1$ for every bounded stopping time $T$.
Now let $M,N$ be two continuous local martingales, then the question is to show that $Z_T=M^T(N-N^T)$ is a continuous local martingale for all stopping times $T$.
Here is my approach: Given that $M,N$ are continuous local martingales, there exists a fundamental sequence of stopping times $T^n$ so that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the processes $M^{T^n}$ and $N^{T^n}$ are bounded martingales. Now if $X$ and $Y$ are two continuous bounded martingales, then using the first statement, to show that $W_T=X^T(Y-Y^T)$ is a bounded martingale, all that we have to show is that $W_T\in L^1$ and $\mathbb{E}W_T=\mathbb{E}W_0$. Clearly, by the boundedness of $X,Y$, it follows that $W_T\in L^1$ and moreover, $X,Y$ are uniformly integrable so that $Y_t=\mathbb{E}(Y_\infty\mid\mathcal{F}_t)$ for $Y_\infty\in L^1$ and so $X_T=\lim_{t\to\infty}X_{t}^T$ which shows that
$$
\mathbb{E}X_T(Y_\infty-Y_T)=\mathbb{E}X_T\mathbb{E}(Y_\infty-Y_T\mid\mathcal{F}_T)=0.
$$
Now is it as simple as saying that for $M,N$ continuous local martingales, that
$$
\mathbb{E}(M^T_t(N_t-N_t^T))^{T^n}=\mathbb{E}M^{T\wedge T^n}_t\mathbb{E}(N^{T^n}_t-N^{T\wedge T^n}_t\mid\mathcal{F}_{T})=\mathbb{E}M_{T\wedge T^n}\mathbb{E}(N_{T^n}-N_{T\wedge T^n}\mid\mathcal{F}_{T})=0
$$
concluding that $M^T(N-N^T)$ is a continuous local martingale by virtue of the first statement, or is there a step missing or wrong in my current attempt?

Your initial observation (for bounded martingales) suffices, because the map $(M,N)\mapsto M^T(N-N^T)$ commutes with stopping: If $(T_n)$ reduces both $M$ and $N$ to bounded martingales, then it does the same for $M^T(N-N^T)$.
